# JSON in Python error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract text from a JSON file in python, but I am receiving the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The code I am trying to run:

```
import json 
  
with open('file.json', encoding="utf-8") as json_file: 
    thing = json.load(json_file) 
    print(thing['text'])
```

The JSON file: (a shortened example of what I'm using)

```
{
  "resources": "https://www.example.com",
  "id": 1,
  "joined": [],
  "text": "Hello.\n The dog sat. \n\n The cat ran",
  "urls": [
    "https://www.example.com",
    "https://www.example.com",
    "https://www.example.com"
  ]
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions for how to solve this error. (I've seen a few similar questions, but they seem to deal with API issues. Apologies if I'm missing something!)

(I am new to stack overflow and JSON, so I sincerely apologize if this is not a good question!)

Answer (score 0):

I received an error concerning control characters. This was solved with double slashes.

Try this code:

```
ss = '''
{
  "resources": "https://www.example.com",
  "id": 1,
  "joined": [],
  "text": "Hello.\\n The dog sat. \\n\\n The cat ran",
  "urls": [
    "https://www.example.com",
    "https://www.example.com",
    "https://www.example.com"
  ]
}
'''.strip()

with open('file.json','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write test file

#####################

import json 
  
with open('file.json', encoding="utf-8") as json_file: 
    thing = json.load(json_file) 
    print(thing['text'])
```

Output

```
Hello.
 The dog sat.

 The cat ran
```